# VB.NET SerialPort send strings and bytes

Tags: vb.net

I'm stuck at the moment because it seems like I'm really mixing up things and I am not able to test it because there are so many conversions and I'm not sure what happens where. I'm sure you can resolve that :)

I need to send strings and bytes over serial.

Sending a string is easy: SerialPort.Write(text)

But I also need to send bytes. How do I send the byte-value 50 to the SerialPort? NOT the integer 50 converted to byte! How do I go about this exactly?

SerialPort.Write(50, 0, 1) says 50 is an integer. How do I make this a byte?

Here's the reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Cheers and thanks!

Comment: You can use SerialPort.BaseStream.WriteByte()

Comment: thanks! I'll definitely try it

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
    Dim b() As Byte = {50}
    yourSerailPort.Write(b, 0, 1)
```

Comment: thank you! There would be a lot such lines (hardcoded initializing of a device), so this would look awful, but if this is how it has to be, I can live with it ;)

Comment: If you have to send many bytes then just change the byte array.